# How to get the date diff between 2 tables for a range using Spark dataframe

Tags: python

I am tryinging to convert the below spark Sql query to Spark Dataframe.

I have `Orders` table `(OrderID, CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate, ShipperID)` and `Shippers` table `(ShipperID, ShipperName, OrderDate)`.

My Spark SQL query lists the number of orders sent by each shipper:

```
 sqlContext.sql("SELECT Shippers.ShipperName, COUNT(Orders.ShipperID) 
    AS NumberOfOrders FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Shippers ON 
    Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID  AND Shippers. OrderDate >= Orders.OrderDate 
    AND datediff(from_unixtime(cast(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Shippers.OrderDate,
    'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')as date)),from_unixtime(cast(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Orders.
    OrderDate,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')as date))) BETWEEN 1 and 10 
    GROUP BY ShipperName")
```

I am okay with the entire join group by query conversion.The issue is with the date time conversion and get the difference between 1 to 10 days.

Here is the dataframe which I have as of now. But my casting is giving errors

```
Shippers.alias("s").join(
    Orders.alias("o"),
    on = "ShipperID",
    how = "left"
).groupby(
    "s.ShipperName"
).select(datediff(from_unixtime(cast(unix_timestamp('OrderDate', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').alias('unix_time'))).between(1,10))).agg(
    F.count(F.col("o.OrderID")).alias("NumberOfOrders")
).show()
```

Can someone please help me to refactor the above SQL query to Spark Dataframe ?

Comment: What's the issue with datetime conversion? All the functions you have used - `from_unixtime`, `unix_timestamp`, `cast` are all available as Spark functions. Including `between` : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column

Comment: The issue is with the range coming wrong .Mostly i guess because of casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation you want to perform should be this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

Orders.alias('o').join(
    Shippers.alias('s'),
    on = ["ShipperId"],
    how = "left"
).filter(
    (
        F.col("s.OrderDate") >= F.col("o.OrderDate")
    ) &
    (
        F.datediff(
            F.from_unixtime(
                F.unix_timestamp(
                    F.col('s.OrderDate'),
                    'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
                )
            ).cast('date'),
            F.from_unixtime(
                F.unix_timestamp(
                    F.col('o.OrderDate'),
                    'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
                )
            ).cast('date')
        ).between(1,10)
    )

).groupby(
    "ShipperName"
).agg(
    F.count(F.col("o.ShipperID")).alias("NumberOfOrders")
)
```

there could be some changes based on the error but logic should be this